# how to authenticate using Google App password

Tags: java, authentication

Using an (Linux, not Android, based) embedded device, I attempt to access data on a Google Drive. Following the guidance of "Using OAuth 2.0 for Installed Applications", this almost works. The remaining problem is that the renewal token itself expires after 6 month. It is my understanding that since this is an embedded device, there's no user present to ask to provide consent, hence no way to get a new authorization code and consequently no way to get a new renewal token.

I just learned that for google accounts using two-factor authentication, one can obtain application specific "App passwords", which (I believe) don't expire. I haven't seen much in terms of documentation of such though (other than how to acquire them). How would I use them in my application? Can I use such an password to instantiate a com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential?

Comment: you might refer to https://support.google.com/a/answer/1032419?hl=en

Comment: Thanks Paul. https://support.google.com/a/answer/1032419?hl=en however only documents the ClientLogin method. ClientLogin has been deprecated and afaik is not available for Google Drive. So what do I do?